# The expectation of a function from a uniform and conditionally uniform distribution.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

This is from a section on long cycles from Billingsley's Convergence of Probability Measures. Here, $C_u^n$ is the length of the $u$th cycle with $n$ total letters.

I have trouble understanding the equation from the second paragraph. Namely, how do we get 
$$E[f(L_1^n , \frac{L_2^n}{1-L_1^n})] = \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i+j \le n} \frac{1}{1-i/n}f(i/n, \frac{j/n}{1-i/n})?$$
Also how do we make the change of variables to get $\int \int_{[0,1]^2} f(y_1,y_2)dy_1 dy_2$? If I make the straight change of variables $y_1 = x_1$ and $y_2 = x_2 / (1-x_1)$ then I can't get rid of the $1/(1-x_1)$ factor.

I would greatly appreciate any help.

[image]